# How to create and use a form in a custom class in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I need to submit data to a `FormType` outside of a controller in a custom class that is registered as a service. The `FormType` itself is also registered as as service and injected into my custom class (`ApiResponseMapper`). This is a simplified snippet:

class ApiResponseMapper
{
    private $bestSellerListsType;

```
public function mapResponse($response)
{
    $form = $this->bestSellerListsType;
    $form->submit($response);
}

public function __construct(BestsellerListType $bestSellerListsType)
{
    $this->bestSellerListsType = $bestSellerListsType;
}
```

}

The `submit()` method does not exist on the form.

How can I initialize my form properly so that I have access to the `submit()` method?

If the form was used in a controller, I'd have access to the `createForm` method and do:

`$form = $this->createForm('my_form_as_a_service');`

Since I'm trying to use the form in a class that does not extend the `Controller`, there is no such option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `FormFactory` to work with custom form types like you do in controllers. Besides your form inject form factory to your service:

```
arguments: [@your_form, @form.factory]
```

Then use `create` method like you do in controllers:

```
$this->formFactory->create(new MyType(), $data, $options);
```

Btw, Symfony uses `facade` design pattern in controllers that let you easy access to various data. You can just check implementation of controller's method and do same yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd post another in case somebody wants to handle creating a form with `form.factory` in the configuration of the services (`services.yml` in my case):

```
bestseller_list_form_type:
    class: Air\BookishBundle\Form\Type\BestsellerListType
    name:
        - { name: form.type, alias: bestseller_list_form }

bestseller_list_form:
    factory_service: form.factory
    factory_method: create
    class: Symfony\Component\Form\Form
    arguments: [@bestseller_list_form_type]

api_response_mapper:
    class: Air\BookishBundle\Lib\ApiResponseMapper
    arguments: [@bestseller_list_form]
```

This way the factory method is invoked upon object instantiation. Then you have the form ready to use in `api_response_mapper` and there is no need to call the factory manually (`$this->formFactory->create(...);`).